# wrap sequence of English characters using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to wrap a sequence or group of tandem english characters in a `<span>` tag.

In the other words I want to change the style of english language in my texts. So I need to find english characters and wrap them in a `<span>` tag.

The method I'm using now puts every single english character in a `<span>` tag but I want the group of these chars to be in a single `<span>` tag.

*edit:* I want to select and replace a word that is in english language.

For example `"russian russian english russian"`

What I need is wrap the english "Characters" in `<span>` tag:

```
"russian russian <span class='eng'>english</span> russian"
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: What's a tag? What do you mean "wrap"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: by wrap I mean jquery wrap... and tag is HTML tag ... for example I have " something something 12353234 something " . I need to wrap 12353234 in a <span> tag : "something something <span class='nums'>12353234</span> something"

Comment: `"The method I'm using now..."` please detail your method

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to find words.
So you can use something like:

```
\b\S+\b
```

Or if you want replace only word "english" :
Regex:

```
\b(english)\b
```

Change to :

```
<span class='eng'>$1</span>
```

This text :`english russian russian english russian english english.`

Changes to this: `<span class='eng'>english</span> russian russian <span class='eng'>english</span> russian <span class='eng'>english</span> <span class='eng'>english</span>.`

Don't forget to add case insensitive.

Comment: too broad, maybe `\w` or `[a-zA-Z]` or even `[a-zA-Z'-]`

Comment: it depends what he needs

Comment: Thank you ... but I want to select and replace a word that is in english language. For example "russian russian english russian". What I need is wrap the english "Characters" in <span> tag : "russian russian <span class='eng'>english</span> russian"

Comment: so you want change only "english" word or any? From this yours examples I see that only "english". So I updated answer.

Comment: he wants `s/\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b/<span>$1<\/span>/`

Comment: Hi everybody and thank you all (Specially CS ) . Finally did it using "/\w([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)/g"

Comment: Hello again . can anyone tell me why ("hello ?????? World").replace(/\w([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");        returns "<span>ello</span> ?????? <span>orld</span>". Why first character of each match in gone????

Comment: because you have \w in the bigining

Comment: Also you don't need commas, try this one : /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g